# Can't import ExpressVPN profiles in the network manager in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

It even looks completely different... no edit connections like in 16.04 through 17.04, and when I try to import an ExpressVPN profile into the VPN settings in network manager, first of all it says VPN is off (!) and the imports fail because it says the plugin doesn't support import capability. This worked a hell of a lot better AND easier in previous Ubuntu versions.... 17.10 SUX big time.

So how do I import ExpressVPN profiles into VPN now, using the GUI and not the terminal. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I import my settings with IPVanish. To have this working I have to install:
network-manager-openvpn, network-manager-openvpn-gnome to allow me to import the settings.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you much... that was indeed the issue. I had installed network-manager-openvpn BUT didn't realize I also had to install network-manager-openvpn-gnome. Don't remember having to install that in previous versions...